# How to get a target date given a specific date after converting specific date from CET to IST and excluding weekends

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to get a future date and time based on Specific date from the user input. I need to convert from CET to IST and then add some hours based on some conditions and it has to give us a future date excluding weekends and particular time for example if it time is greater than 5pm then it has  to give the next available day.

I have an MVC form where it accepts a date and then i have to convert this date to a future date in C# code.

Can anyone help me in this.

I can give a logic in pseudo code if needed.

Please help me in this. As i am not able to figure out  how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a simple WinForms application with a dateTimePicker and a button to trigger the event:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime d = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    d = d.AddHours(3.5); // add 3.5 hours to move from CET to IST
    switch(d.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            d = d.AddDays(2); // increment day to Monday
            break;
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            d = d.AddDays(1); // increment day to Monday
            break;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(d.ToString("R")); // show value of d in machines regional format
}
```

Hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: Thanks. But i want the result in a textbox and i am already using MVC framework so cannot use Winform so where should i put the code...in the Controller? and i need to bind the result to a textbox for the target date. Also i need to see the time after converting into IST if it is between 8 and 5 then add 4 hours or 9 hours or 45 hours as per the conditions it should give the date keeping in mind the cut off time is 5 pm for e.g if we get IST as 1 pm then if we have to add 4 hours target date would be the same but if we have to add 9 hours then till 5 pm then it is next day and 5 hours from 8am

Comment: Without being able to see your code I can't really say where would be best to put it. As long as you have the value in a DateTime object, the code should work fine for you and you don't need to use MessageBox to show it, just call something like: textBox1.text = d.ToString("R"), or something similar to update your textBox value.

Comment: i have one textbox  known as Recieved Date where i use jquery date time picker  to get the date and time .. From this textbox value i need to convert and get the target date and time based on the above conditions.

Comment: <script src="~/js/datetime_js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script>

            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                'use strict';

                jQuery('#txtRecievedDate').datetimepicker();

            });
</script>

in the model i am setting the class as public string RecievedDate

 public string RecievedDate { get; set; }

Comment: I could add the hours. but i need to get endtime as 5:00 pm and then subtract from ist and if the difference is greater than say 4 hours then add 4 hours target date remains the same. but if difference is less than 4 hours add the difference and then add hours till 8 am next day and then add the remaining hours which 4 hours less the diff added.So i want to know how can i extract the date and set time to end time which 5 pm ..seems complicated !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I used your code and further used my own logic and came up with the final solution which gives me the Target Date as expected.

Below is my code :-

DateTime d =  Convert.ToDateTime(model.RecievedDate);

```
                DateTime end_time = new DateTime(1901,01,01, 17, 0 ,0);

                TimeSpan timeFrom = TimeSpan.Parse(d.ToString("HH:mm"));
                TimeSpan timeTo = TimeSpan.Parse(end_time.ToString("HH:mm"));
                TimeSpan timediff = timeTo.Subtract(timeFrom);

                if (model.Complexity == "L")
                {
                    if (timediff.TotalHours >= 4)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(4);
                    }
                    else if (timediff.TotalHours < 4 && timediff.TotalHours > 0)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(timediff.TotalHours + 15 + (4 - timediff.TotalHours));
                    }
                    else if (timediff.TotalHours < 0)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(timediff.TotalHours + 15 + 4);
                    }
                }
                else if (model.Complexity == "M")
                {
                    if (timediff.TotalHours >= 9)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(9);
                    }
                    else if (timediff.TotalHours < 9 && timediff.TotalHours > 0)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(timediff.TotalHours + 15 + (9 - timediff.TotalHours));
                    }
                    else if (timediff.TotalHours < 0)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(timediff.TotalHours + 15 + 9);
                    }
                }
                else if (model.Complexity == "H")
                {
                    var day = d.ToString("ddd");
                    if (day == "Mon")
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(120);
                    }
                    else if (day == "Tue" || day == "Wed" || day == "Thu")
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(120 + 48);
                    }
                    else if (day == "Fri" && timediff.TotalHours > 0)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(120 + 48);
                    }
                    else if (day == "Fri" && timediff.TotalHours < 0)
                    {
                        d = d.AddHours(timediff.TotalHours + 15 + 48 + 120);
                    }
                }
                switch (d.DayOfWeek)
                {
                    case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                        d = d.AddDays(2);// increment day to Monday
                        break;

                    case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                        d = d.AddDays(1); // increment day to Monday
                        break;
                }
                d = d.AddHours(3.5);
                model.TargetDate = d; // show value of d
```